# IRabbitMqHost autofac registration problem

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, autofac, masstransit

Need to resolve IRabbitMqHost for adding handler to bus after bus started.

Steps to Reproduce

Register "IRabbitMqHost" in masstransit configuration
Try to resolve "IRabbitMqHost" in autofac
Then "Exception of type 'Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException' was thrown"

```cs
builder.Register(context =>
                {
                    var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(opt =>
                    {
                        var result = new List<string>();
                        Configuration.GetSection("RabbitMq:HostNames").Bind(result);

                        var host = opt.Host(result[0], Configuration.GetValue<string>("RabbitMq:VirtualHost"), h =>
                        {
                            h.Username(Configuration.GetValue<string>("RabbitMq:Username"));
                            h.Password(Configuration.GetValue<string>("RabbitMq:Password"));
                        });

                        builder.Register<IRabbitMqHost>(a => host);
                    });
                    return bus;
                }).As<IBus>()
                .As<IBusControl>();

builder.Build().Resolve<IRabbitMqHost>()
```

Expected Behavior
Need to resolve IRabbitMqHost which configured in IBus configuration, because need to add handler after bus started.
Need _rabbitMqHost.ConnectReceiveEndpoint()...

Actual Behavior
container.Resolve throws exception belove.
image in https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/1470

Answer (score 0):

When registered to bus in autofac gave delegate function which create bus instance and registers host. But this delegate not invoked yet. After build the containerbuilder and tried to resolve IBus, then it invoke delegate and registered IRabbitMqHost but not built container. Then when i try to solve IRabbitMqHost it not find registered component because added container not built.

this code worked for me;

```
builder.Register(context =>
                {
                    var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(opt =>
                    {
                        var result = new List<string>();
                        Configuration.GetSection("RabbitMq:HostNames").Bind(result);

                        var host = opt.Host(result[0], Configuration.GetValue<string>("RabbitMq:VirtualHost"), h =>
                        {
                            h.Username(Configuration.GetValue<string>("RabbitMq:Username"));
                            h.Password(Configuration.GetValue<string>("RabbitMq:Password"));
                        });
                        ContainerBuilder b = new ContainerBuilder();
                        b.Register<IRabbitMqHost>(a => host).SingleInstance();
                        b.Update(ApplicationContainer);
                    });
                    return bus;
                }).As<IBus>()
                .As<IBusControl>()
                .SingleInstance();
``
```